# How do I map an array of objects one at a time depending on it's index?

Tags: reactjs

Here, I'm trying to show images and titles depending on the value of num. Since the index from 0-4 is supposed to have random images, when I press the next button, the title changes but the images remain the same it doesn't update. How do I map this in a way that every time I press the next button, the different images come?

```
export default class MainContainer extends Component { 
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    posts: [
        {
            "title": "Title 1",
            "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 2",
            "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 3",
            "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 4",
            "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 5",
            "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 6",
            "image": "https://www.instagram.com/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/4272e394f5ad.png"
          }
    ],
    num : 0,
  }
}

nextPic = () => {
   if(this.state.num > 4) {
       this.setState({
           num : 0
       })
   } else {
       this.setState({
           num : this.state.num + 1
       })
   }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.posts[this.state.num].title}</h1>
            <img src={this.state.posts[this.state.num].image} />
            <button onClick={this.nextPic}>Next</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Btw it's not a react issue, it's an issue of unsplash, faced that one earlier.

If you will have different paths it will work as needed.

Comment: Ohh, that makes so much sense. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a ReactJS problem. If you will have a normal paths to images, and they will be different everything will render properly with different images.

Somehow **unsplash** and **picsum** return same images when you iterate with their random paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the url in some way in every call for react to detect change and re-render a new image. One way to do it is append a query with a random integer to the url.

For eg:-

```
getImageSource() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    return `https://source.unsplash.com/random?${randomNumber}`;
}
```

Working example:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/z30qom5m8x?fontsize=14